# Why is it possible to get insignificant F statistic (p>0.1) but significant regressor t-tests (p<0.1)?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, t-test, f-test

My results show significant t-tests but an insignificant F-test. Is this possible or are my calculations wrong?